How to better append html response content to a Node.JS pug template?
My Node.JS app makes an external API call which returns markdown response. I then use https://github.com/showdownjs/showdown toconvert it to HTML and append it to a scrollable list in the following pug template.
extends layout
block append head
script(src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/showdown/2.1.0/showdown.min.js')
block layout-content
  h1.title Welcome to #{title}
  section.section.chat-container
    .container
      .columns
        .box.column.is-full
          .chat-messages.has-text-left
            p#messages
          form#chatForm(action='/api', method='post', enctype="multipart/form-data")
            .field.has-addons
              p.control.is-expanded
                input(class='input', id='query', type='text', placeholder='How can I help?', onkeyup="stoppedTyping()")
              p.control
                input(class='button is-success', id="submit", type='submit', value='Submit', disabled)
      script.
        document.querySelector("#chatForm").addEventListener("submit", async (e) => {
          e.preventDefault();
          const query = document.querySelector("#query").value;
          if (query.trim()) {
            const response = await fetch('/api', {
              method: 'POST',
              body: form
            });
            const data = await response.json();
            var converter = new showdown.Converter();
            document.querySelector("#messages").innerHTML += `<p><strong>Query:</strong> ${query}</p>`;
            document.querySelector("#messages").innerHTML += `<p><strong>Response:</strong></p>${converter.makeHtml(data.message)}<br>`;
          }
        } else 
            console.error(`Invalid query!`);
        });

It doesn't work quite well. All I see is only paragraph with bold and normal fonts. For example, the bullet- or number lists returned in the HTML response is outside of the container box.

can you do it?
Explanation of Changes
Container Adjustments:
By using a div container rather than <p>, the HTML structure from Markdown (like bullet points or numbered lists) can be displayed correctly.
Error Handling:
The try-catch block and network check if (!response.ok) help ensure robust error handling, displaying errors if the API call fails.
Clearing Input and Disabling Submit Button:
After each successful query, the input field clears, and the submit button is disabled until new text is entered.
